# Can I make the whole drawer clickable with MMdrawerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, touches, mmdrawercontroller

I'm using `MMdrawerController` for an `Objective-C` project and it works well using this hamburger icon on the `drawer` to trigger it to open and close. When the `drawer` is closed, it rests at the edge of the right side of the screen until it's opened again by clicking the hamburger icon. Now, I would like to make the whole `drawer` clickable instead of just the icon, so that the drawer opens wherever I click on it.

Is there a straight forward way to do this, because the only thing I really can think of is creating an invisible button where the `drawer` is and make that trigger the open/close code.

The code for triggering the drawer looks like this:

```
[self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
```

***EDIT***
I tried using both `touchesBegan` as well as `UITapGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"PRESS");
}
```

and

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

```
-(void)tapped {
    NSLog(@"TAPPED");
}
```

They only get triggered when the `drawer` has already been opened and I press somewhere in the `viewController`, but it doesn't trigger when the `drawer` is resting to the side of the screen (when it is closed).

Comment: You can add a TapGestureRecognizer to your drawerController's view

Comment: I did add the `touchesEnded` delegate to the `class` that the `drawer` currently contain, but it only triggered on touches when the `drawer` had already been opened, not when it rests at the right side of the screen. What am I missing?

Comment: I also tried using `UITapGestureRecognizer` but with the same results: it works when the `drawer` has been opened already, but not when it's resting at the side.